# Transfer of left Bousfield localization

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories, bousfield-localization

My first question in this forum. 
Suppose we have a Quillen equivalence $L: M\leftrightarrow N: R$ between two model categories (say left proper cofibrantly generated cellular or locally presentable). Let $S$ a set of morphisms in $M$ and $L(S)=T$ the image of S in $N$.

I was wondering if $L: \mathbf{L}_{S}M\leftrightarrow \mathbf{L}_{T}N: R$ is a Quillen equivalence? $\mathbf{L}_{S}M$ is the left Bousfield localization of $M$ at $S$ and $\mathbf{L}_{T}N$ is the left Bousfield localization of $N$ at $T=L(S)$

**Remark:** $L(S)$ is the ordinary image **not** the derived one (as in David White answer), there is no cofibrant replacement.
**Edit**: I was wondering if there is a clear answer to my question ? The only reference I have found is [here, page 5017 just after theorem 5.7](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2001-353-12/S0002-9947-01-02661-7/S0002-9947-01-02661-7.pdf) But I'm still not satisfied since there is no proof and the cited version uses Hirschhorn book where the author (Hirschhorn) deals with the derived image. I will be happy for any clear answer, thank you.

Comment: This is not true if $L$ does not preserve weak equivalences. Take $S=\{f\}$ where $f$ is a weak equivalence and $L(f)$ isn't. Then $L_SM=M$ but $N\rightleftarrows L_TN$ is not a Quillen equivalence.

Comment: Thanks for the useful counterexample. I'm surprised that in the paper I have mentioned there is such imprecision!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This is Theorem 3.3.20 in Hirschhorn's book, if by $T$ you mean the left derived maps of $L(S)$, e.g. cofibrant replacements of the maps $L(S)$.

Comment: In my initial question $T=L(S)$ not the derived image as you assumed.

Comment: You can take the cofibrant replacement of maps in $L(S)$ to get a new set of maps $T'$. It is easy to see that $L_{T'}N$ is the same as $L_{L(S)}N$. I used that trick in my thesis, and Hovey has used it in several of his papers.

Comment: thanks @davidwhite do you a precise statement in your references ?

Comment: It's just the 2 out of 3 property. Given a map $f:A\to B$, let $Qf:QA\to QB$ be its cofibrant replacement. Picture the square featuring $Qf$ and $f$. The legs are cofibrant replacement maps for A and B, so they are weak equivalences. If you invert Qf, then it's a new weak equivalence. By the 2 out of 3 property, f is also a new weak equivalence.

Comment: But still I don't understand why you can conclude that $L_{L(S)}N$ is equivalent to $L_{T^{'}} N$ (I'm using your definition of $T^{'}$).

Comment: Well, they have the same cofibrations (because both are localizations of N) and they have the same weak equivalences: the 2/3 property in $L_{T'}N$ tells you all the maps in $L(S)$ are weak equivalences there, and the 2/3 property in $L_{L(S)}N$ tell you all maps in $T'$ are weak equivalences there. So the model structures coincide.

Comment: For simplicity suppose that $S=\{f\}$, then I see how your argument works to compare $L_{f}M$ and $L_{Qf}M$ but i think it fails to compare $L_{L(f)}N$ and $L_{L(Qf)}N$. It is clear that $L_{f}M$ and $L_{Qf}M$ are equivalent and it is clear that $L_{Qf}M$ is equivalent to $L_{L(Qf)}N$. But  hoe to prove that $L_{L(f)}N$ and $L_{L(Qf)}N$ are equivalent ? what we know is that $L_{L(f)}N$ is equivalent to $L_{QL(f)}N$ but not more. I'm getting it right ?

Comment: I never took L(Qf). I said you should do cofibrant replacement of L(S), i.e. cofibrant replacement in $N$. So $L_SM$ is equivalent to $L_{T'} N$ by Hirschhorn, and that coincides with $L_{L(S)} N$ (which you agree with in your comment). But even if you did cofibrant replacement in $M$ that would be okay, because $L$ is a left Quillen equivalence, so it preserves cofibrant objects and weak equivalences.

Comment: Do you agree that to answer my posted question you need to prove at some point  that $L_{L(f)}N$ is equivalent to $L_{L(Qf)}N$. Otherwise I really don't see how you make the conclusion. Sorry if I'm too slow, I need to be convinced :) The trick you are using is that  $L_{QL(f)}N$ is equivalent to $L_{L(f)}N$ which is true as you explained but it is not enough to answer the posted question.

Comment: I don't agree that you need to prove that, but anyway it's true, as I said in my last comment, using the fact that $L$ is a left Quillen equivalence. Just follow your nose and you will write a correct proof.

Comment: I think I see. Your interpretation (which I guess is not correct) of Theorem 3.3.20 is different : suppose for simplicity that $S=\{f\}$ then the theorem says that $L_{f}M$ is equivalent to $L_{LQf}N$ while in your interpretation it seems that you are saying that $L_{f}M$ is equivalent to $L_{QLf}N$ and I think it is not what the theorem says.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I checked Hirschhorn, and you're right that I had the convention backwards. I still think it doesn't matter, since $LQ$ and $QL$ have equivalent images, both contained in the cofibrant objects of $N$ (since $L$ is left Quillen). Anyway, $L_{L(f)}N$ is the same as $L_{L(Qf)}N$ because $L(f)$ is a new weak equivalence if and only if $L(Qf)$ is one, by 2/3, since $L$ preserves weak equivalences. So either way, I remain convinced that you're done, by 3.3.20.

Comment: I don't think that $L_{L(Qf)}N$ is the same as $L_{L(f)}$. $LQ$ and $QL$ are really different in general.